# how to get the cell at index path.item - 1 in collection view

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to access the previous cell (index path.item - 1) in my collection view to change some settings there if  some conditions are fulfilled in the  cell at index path.item

By now I tried this:

```
        let previousCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath - 1)
```

But it doesn't work because of the - 1 it is downcast from index path to an integer value.

How do I get this cell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check :

```
let previousCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: indexPath.row-1, section: indexPath.section))
```

To get cell with identifier :

```
let prevIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row-1, section: indexPath.section)
let previousCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: prevIndexPath)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for productive answer. It does work, but just gives back an uicollectionviewcell. Is it possible to get this cell with an specific identifier?

Answer (score 1):

What does "previous cell" even mean? Do you mean the same section but the previous row? Then construct an index path with a `row` less than this row.

However, the question itself seems to indicate a total misconception about how table views work. You should not need to "access" any cells at all. Update your *model* and reload the table (or the relevant cells).

Comment: Thanks vor your answer. I am creating  a Chat application. if someone is wrting three messages in a row. I only want to show his profile picture next to the thrid message, similiar to what it is like in facebook messanger. And this was my first idea how to solve this becausenby now next to every message it shows the profileimage

Comment: and if you are only here to hate, pls don't answer these questions or in a more positive manner.

Comment: Nobody's "hating". Your question suggests that you misunderstand how to use table views, as Matt says. iOS uses the MVC design pattern, where view objects display data from a model object. If you want to change some data that's at a different indexPath, you need to change the data MODEL at that location, and then tell the cell to update.